# spring mvc how to configure url mapping

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring mvc. I just want to implement this:

I have following urls, I want them all be handled by just one controller:

```
/entity/*
```

in web.xml, I defined dispatcher servlet like this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/etc/webmvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/action/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/data/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/entity/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/entity")
public class EntityController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/*")
    public @ResponseBody Object operate(@RequestBody EntityOperationRequest dataReq){
        return null;
    }

}
```

this does not work, how can I make my `EntityController` to handle all urls begin with `/entity/`, so following url will hit it:

```
http://host:port/CONTEXT_ROOT/entity/sys/User
http://host:port/CONTEXT_ROOT/entity/biz/Order
http://host:port/CONTEXT_ROOT/entity/biz/foo/bar
....
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different levels upto which you can perform URL mapping (like Class level, method level etc.)
This example will help you.
[Spring MVC @RequestMapping Annotation Example](http://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-mvc-requestmapping-annotation-example-with-controller-methods-headers-params-requestparam-pathvariable)